# how to get ALL amount_left with ALL partyname checking that ALL partyname same as in another table with in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here is the First Table:

Sales:

```
Restaurant Teliabagh    80000
Restaurant Teliabagh    20000
SHRI BALAJI 50000
Bhola ji    50000
Ajay    50000
```

Second Tables:

Cash:

```
Restaurant Teliabagh    20000 
Restaurant Teliabagh    20000 
Ajay    25000
```

I was able to get **money_left** for one party **AJAY** **only amount** not with his name

here is the command:

```
SELECT (select sum(totalamount) from acc.sales where Partyname='Ajay')-(select sum(Amountrecevied) from acc.cash where Party_name='Ajay') as money_left;
```

and output as

> money_left
>
> 25000

BUT my problem is that Here I want to display the **ALL Partyname with Money_left** After subtraction (totalamount) of the partynames in sales table form (amount received) in cash tables.

IT will be fine if it displays partyname and amount as NUll after subtraction them.

Comment: Please post sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images we can't. Also how is this different to your post of an hour ago which was closed as a duplicate?

Comment: i did it and in that different post i wrote the question incomplete i am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Partyname, sales.totalamount - COALESCE(cash.totalamount, 0) as money_left
FROM ( SELECT Partyname, SUM(totalamount) totalamount
       FROM acc.sales
       GROUP BY 1 ) sales
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Partyname, SUM(totalamount) totalamount
            FROM acc.cash
            GROUP BY 1 ) cash USING (Partyname);
```

If there exists `Partyname` value which is present in `cash` but is absent in `sales` then additional subquery with UNION DISTINCT which gathers all `Partyname` values needed as a base.